# Form input history select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been struggling to deal with a few forms that have users entering in a lot of repeat data. In these cases it helps users to have access to form history (ie. to select the name of a person they've sent multiple notices to, etc. The issue here is that **in most browsers there is no event fired with a user selects a chunk of text from their form history**. So with the help of a few other posts on stackoverflow I decided to use `setInterval` instead.

What I'm looking for now is feedback to spot anything that might be a bad idea and anything to make this better.

I have a demo of it here http://lab.atworkinthecloud.com/form-history-select/

Comment: It seems to never update it's current value variable, so anything that deviated from the first value is considered a "change".

Comment: I have the same issue.  However, your "setInterval" solution is the only one I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't base your implementation on the behavior of the browser (remembering the history), which might or might not be available to the user.
If you want to design a useful interface, you should provide the access to the history yourself, or use features like [autocomlete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: I hope I'm not misunderstood - this is not a 'base' for anything. Just a few lines of code to solve a specific, existing problem that has been identified.

Answer (score 0):

since you trigger the handler so frequently , (and I noticed that you also bind the propterychange event), then why don't just bind the propertychange only, that will do it as well.

you don't need to bind all those events at all.

I met the same problem, but I still prefer to have a way that only trigger the hanlder after the user finished typing.

Comment: As the OP states, the "onchange" event isn't fired when you click an item from your form history, even after you move focus!